# What happens completing "Smoke on the water" missions?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

What happens after you complete all the "smoke on the water" missions as Franklin?

Answer (score 1):

After purchasing the venue, the manager will occasionally contact Franklin to help run the pharmacy, in the form of product pick-up and delivery missions.

This business produces a weekly income of $9,300 and will take 22 weeks to turn a profit over the initial investment.

According to [IGN](https://www.ign.com/wikis/gta-5/Property_Missions):

> With the purchase of each profit-based property comes optional missions to **help generate even more profit** for the business.